# Passing object to a function to use common functionality among distinct C# classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView and a DetailsView in a ASP.NET webpage, I will need to extract either one or the other for its information and I've made a function for this. Both GridView and DetailsView have a property named Rows which is what I need to use in my function.

So in code I have something as follows:

```
// Where dv is DetailsView and gv is GridView
if(someBool) 
   foo(dv); 
else
   foo(gv);
```

Where foo would look as follows:

```
void foo(SomeBaseClassOrInterface dv) {
    foreach(var row in dv.Rows) {
       Use(row.Cells[2].Text); // Simply read each row
     }
}
```

Rather than making two different functions, I figure I can use the same one since the operations for DetailsViewRowCollection and GridViewRowCollection are mirrors of each other. Problem is I don't seen to have a base class that shares the Rows property.

I tried creating two classes that inherit from DetailsView and GridView and simply use their parent's Row property, both implement an interface which I then use in my main code, but that doesn't seem to be working. Reason being the return type of Rows for DetailsView and GridView differ, both return types inherit from IEnumerable but any class that implements the interface will need to have its Row property also return an IEnumerable, using generics bypasses this limitation but then fails in my calling code which complains that my object which implements GridView and DetailsView can not be converted to the Interface type.

I feel there's a very simple solution I'm missing. Perhaps it might be easier to just duplicate code in this case?

I'm trying to find a good approach that ideally avoids duplicate code.

Thanks

Comment: Since they share no base class (other than `Object`), like you say, there's really no way to handle the code in the same method.  I think you've simplified it as much as you can, by pulling out your logic into the `Use` method.  That way the only code you duplicate is the looping, which is pretty fair IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your function accepting an IEnumerable, and because GridViewRow and DetailsViewRow derive from TableRow, you can use a TableRow as the enumeration variable:

```
void foo(IEnumerable enumerable) {
    foreach(TableRow row in enumerable) {
       Use(row.Cells[2].Text); // Simply read each row
     }
}
```

You will have to pass the Rows to the function:

```
if(someBool) 
   foo(dv.Rows); 
else
   foo(gv.Rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
if(someBool) 
   Use(dv.SelectMany(x => x.Rows).SelectMany(x => x.Cells[2].Text));
else
   Use(gv.SelectMany(x => x.Rows).SelectMany(x => x.Cells[2].Text));
```

And changing the `Use()` method to accept an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a single string.

Still looks like violating DRY, but you've removed the `foo()` method.

Answer (score 0):

One option - create "extractor" interface that will deal with getting information from either of this. Add 2 implementations - one for `GridView`, another for `DetailsView`.

```
class CellType
{
   // some fields that are interesting like
   public string Text {get;set;}
}

class Row {
   public List<CellType> Cells {get;set}
}

interface IRowExtractor
{ 
     IEnumerable<Row> Rows {get};
}

class GVRowExtractor : IRowExtractor
{
   List<Rows> rows;
   public GVRowExtractor(GridView gv)
   {
        // fill Rows from gv
   }
   public IEnumerable<Row> Rows {get {return rows;}};
}

class DVRowExtractor : IRowExtractor ....

void foo(IRowExtractor dv) {
  foreach(var row in dv.Rows) {
     Use(row.Cells[2].Text); // Simply read each row
 }
}
```

Usage:

```
foo(new DVRowExtractor(dv));
```